# jquery Fancybox is returning error on certain photos but different ones each time

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I followed the instructions to include the code as required and the js files and it works when on my computer and when uploaded to the server on a temporary working site I use. But when I upload it to the client's site (and it's to the same server) I get the error code "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later." on about half the photos BUT the photos that produce the error are different each time I go to the page. 
Makes no sense.

Here's the page on the web http://smittysbar.com/gallery.htm

I do have two instances of jquery in the code because I'm using the other for a Simple Jquery Slideshow on a different page. Are they in conflict? -

Here's the code on the gallery page-

```
<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.3"></script>   
<link href="jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and here's the code the page gets from the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Here's the page that uses the other jquery instance:
http://smittysbar.com/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

The problem I'm seeing is that some of the images are not being delivered to Fancybox.  For instance one of your anchors wants to have fancybox show http://smittysbar.com/images/galleryLG/08.JPG but when viewing the item in my browser I get a 404 error.

It might be a case issue.  Change all your .JPGs to .jpg.